# Tagging and categorizing very short texts

Tags: database, text-processing

I am a historian, working on ancient texts. I want to be able to manually tag items in a long list of citations (each usually very short, e.g., Ovid Met. 1.4.5, Hom. Odyss. 4.5.6) so I can then retrieve a list of citations by clicking or searching a certain tag. Ideally tags could be hierarchized and nested etc. 
A full scale database seems to be too much for this. I would like all of the citations and tags to be in one file, and if possible online. The main point is to be able to create it as fast as possible, i.e., each item with as little clicks as possible. 
I have no programming capabilities.
Many thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] and add some info: OS, price. What are your citations currently stored in? And are your examples examples of tags?

Comment: I don't think this is a direct solution, but maybe [DocEar](http://www.docear.org/) is worth looking at.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know what you're currently using for text processing – and whether the tags should be attached to entire documents, or rather to single phrases/lines/paragraphs within a document.